# Will Google Docs break my Word Document

Tags: microsoft-word, google-docs

I have a word document that I want to work with in Google docs.

How can i know it will not be broken (That i cant get it back as a word document comparable to the one I uploaded, with the changes i have made).

If this is difficult, any online apps similar to Google Docs which are closer to word?

Comment: This question should be migrated to webapps

Comment: Try it first. Then let us know if you have any problems.

Comment: I suspect this would get closed on webapps as well.

Comment: Strange that this question is bad, as would be, I assume, a question about MS Office 365, but a question about MS Office 2010 is okay. The line draws ever thinner…

Comment: An answer could be a way to compare what you get back with the original document (So "cannot be reasonably answered in its current form" is wrong QED).  Also it shows that this is not a web-app question.

Comment: @iglvzx: Trying it would only demonstrate that it doesn't break one particular document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it loads into google docs fine it will save fine as a regular word doc. As long as you are not using some outlandish stuff in your word docs they will 99% of the time load just fine into google docs.

Comment: This has not been my experience with importing Word documents into Google Docs. Documents that I import will regularly have large portions of the formatting removed, though the original plaintext is typically there. Also, during the importing process, Google Docs will *not* notify you that it has stripped unsupported formatting from the document.